# skip reading row if condition fails usig java

Tags: java, for-loop, arraylist

i want to skip one full row( one iteration) if something like tempVal0 is not blank also tempVal1 is not blank. then my pointer should skip reading that particular row and and go for fetching next set of values  . Note this is a list of list of string not an excel table

#### secmsisdn primrymsisdn code

23434   85353340324 2
23423   85352340326 2
-       85358340325 2

```
            int forindex=0;  
           for (List<String> tempList : userInputList) {
            List<String> innerList = new ArrayList<String>();
            //DB Variables



            // 0 SecondaryMSISDN
            String tempVal0 = tempList.get(0);
            if(validate.isNumeric(tempVal0)){ 
                innerList.add(tempVal0);
            }else{
                innerList.add("");

            }

            // 1 PrimaryMSISDN
            String tempVal1 = tempList.get(1);
            if(validate.isMSISDN18(tempVal1)){ 
                innerList.add(tempVal1);
            }else{
                innerList.add("");

            }

            // 2 Code 
            String tempVal2 = tempList.get(2);
            if(validate.isShort(tempVal2)){ 
                innerList.add(tempVal2);
            }else {
                innerList.add("");
            }

            bulkUyData.add(innerList);
            forindex++;
        }
```

i am able to add values one by one into the innerlist . But i want to check if both the column 1 and 2 have values then it should skip that row.

Comment: What about the entries you already created in innerList when skipping a line. Do you want to keep them?

Answer (score 1):

Use the **continue** keyword in the loop, this will cause the loop to skip the current iteration and go for the next.

```
if(condition){
  continue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you mean to skip the current row just use `continue`.

If you mean to skip the next row then rather than using a foreach loop use either an iterator or an index. You can then add 1 to the index or move on one in the iterator inside your loop.